# How to multiply an int with a fraction

Tags: c, binary, logic, bit-manipulation

I need to multiply an int by a fraction using bitwise operators without loops and such.

For example, I need to multiply by x by 3/8.

I thought you would:

```
int value = (x << 1) + x;  // Multiply by 3
value = (value >> 3);          // Divide by 8
```

But that doesnt work. I tried googling binary times fraction but that give floating point examples. I dont know exactly if this homework is for floating point but my hunch is no but getting me prepared for it. So any suggestions?

---

I need to round toward zero so any suggestions? This doesnt work for the number -268435457.

Comment: Are you saying that the updated code still doesn't work?  Is `x` an int?  also, what is the value of `x` that you tried and the resulting `value`

Comment: Is this still not working?! You made an edit from a solution below it looks like...

Comment: The solution round up instead of down, towards 0.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
int value = (x << 1) + x;
value = (value >> 3);
```

note that:

```
(x << 1) + 1 = 2*x + 1; // ignoring issues about overflow
```

To adjust for negative values, you can explicitly check for sign:

```
int value = (x << 1) + x;
value = value >> 3;
value = value + ((x >> 31) & 1); // for 32 bit; for 64 bit you have to use x >> 63
```

Comment: And then 'value = (value >> 3)'

Comment: @Andrey updated (thought it was obvious but should be stated for completeness)

Comment: This is wrong for the number -268435457. I return -100663297 but should return -100663296. It is rounding up. How can I round down?

Comment: You are trying to use a negative value.  You can either check for sign and negate the final result, or explicitly add in the sign bit.  I will update my response

Comment: Is there a way to do it without conditional statements. I can only use bitwise operators like >> << ~ ! + & ^

Comment: I cant use the ? and : operation but this gives the wrong answer for -268435457. It gives 33554433 instead of -100663296.

Comment: @seg_fault are you compiling 32 or 64 bit?  in the 64 bit case, the shift should be `((x >> 63) & 1)`

Comment: 32 bit. Does that number work on yours? I have tried mine a few times but nothing. This is the gcc command I am using: gcc -O -Wall -m32 -lm -o btest

Comment: This method doesn't work if the actual result is a negative whole number. Input of -24 gives -8 instead of -9.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
int value = (x << 1) + x;  // Multiply by 3
value = (value >> 3);      // Divide by 8
```

i.e. in your second statement replace 'x' with 'value'. Also, value will loose the decimal points.

Comment: I want to ignore decimal points and round down which is the same as ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an overflow you can cast to (long long) and back to (int) for the final result.  To cause the `>> 3` to round toward zero you need to add 7 (8-1) for a negative number.  There are a few ways of doing this. Using these approaches gives you -100663296.