# Multiply by 5/8 and watch for overflow

Tags: c, overflow, bit-manipulation

I'm really close to finally breaking this thing, but still I have no idea how to watch for the overflow on this.

```
int multFiveEighths(int x) {

    int y=((x<<2)+x);
    int f=((y>>3)+1);
    int z=(y>>3);



    return f + ((~!(x>>31&1)+1) & (z+~f+1));
```

I multiply by 5/8, and use a conditional bitwise to say:
If the sign bit is 1 (number is negative), use f, else z.

A part of this is to include overflow behavior like the C expression (x*5/8)

So how do I include the overflow behavior?
I can only use these ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
No loops, no casting, no declaring of functions.
I'm so close that it's painful.

EDIT

I have to implement rounding towards zero.

Comment: You're throwing some bits out on the left, overflow happens when they are not all equal.

Comment: How sould I go about stopping that? I really have no clue, but I would be greatful if you told be what to do.

Comment: Note that **overflow of signed integers, and left-shifting of negative integers, are undefined behaviour**. So the problem is not well posed (I'd love to have a word with your "professor" about that!).

Comment: Why the " around professor? But I'm just as lost...

Comment: What are you even doing? I don't understand this code at all. `((~!(x>>31&1)+1)` This means shift x right by 31, needlessly mask out the lsb giving you the same number as you had before & operator, either 1 or 0, then inverse the 1 or 0, then set all bits to their opposite. At this point you either have 0xFFFFFFFE or 0xFFFFFFFF. On top of that useless binary number you add 1, ending up with either 0xFFFFFFFF or overflow. Don't write obfuscated one-line messes like this!

Comment: Also you are doing bitwise operations on signed numbers, which is a bad idea. `z + ~f` for example, will yield a negative number, because ~f will always be interpreted as a negative number.

Comment: This is essentially the same thing as asked here btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356927/how-to-multiply-an-int-with-a-fraction but I don't really feel it was adequately answered there

Comment: @harold, yeah it's what I was asking, but as you said. It ends in basically the same error.

Comment: @Lundin The return statement is a conditional so if it's a negative, round up, if not, round down (towards zero in general). If you want to help, please do, but have it constructive.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the ?: ternary operator ?

Comment: @wildplasser No, but the code I have above in the return statement is the bit equivelant of that.

Comment: @Zanii It is pretty constructive to point out that your code relies on completely undefined behavior, I would think.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = num >> 3; // divide by 8 (only defined for positive values)

x = x << 2 + x;   // multiply by 5; no overflow yet since 5/8 is less than one

int y = num & 7;  // the bits we shifted out

y = y << 2 + y;   // multiply by 5; no overflow

return (x + (y >> 3)); // the two pieces
```

ADDENDUM, round toward zero for negative:

```
int s = -((num >> 31) & 1); // sign bit as -1 or 0

int n = (num ^ s) - s; // twos complement if negative

int x = n >> 3; // divide by 8

x = (x << 2) + x;   // multiply by 5; no overflow yet since 5/8 is less than one

int y = n & 7;  // the bits we shifted out

y = (y << 2) + y;   // multiply by 5; no overflow

return (s ^ (x + (y >> 3))) - s; // the two pieces and complemented back
```

Comment: It gives -167772161[0xf5ffffff]. Should be -167772160[0xf6000000].
The error I get. Same as before... I was hoping this would finally solve it. Damn.

Comment: @Zanii you could try subtracting `num >> 31` from the result, bit of a hack I suppose..

Comment: @harold Didn't work, same error. Always 1 from the correct answer.

Comment: OK, did't realize you needed round toward zero; see addendum

Comment: @DougCurrie There is it. Thank you very much.

Comment: This code relies on undefined behavior, you should change it to use unsigned integer types.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this was what you were searching for:

```
int multFiveEights(int x) {

  int isneg = (x>>31);

  // Negative x
  int nx = -x;

  int value = ( (~!!(isneg)+1) &  nx ) + ( (~!(isneg)+1) & x );

  /* Now its positive */
  value = (value<<2) + value;
  value = value & ((-1)>>1); // This mask should produce the desired overflow behavior
  value = (value>>3);

  value = ( (~!!(isneg)+1) & (-value)) + ( (~!(isneg)+1) & (value));

  return value;
}
```

The idea is quite simple:

1. convert whatever the argument is to a positive number
2. mask the most significant bit to 0 after the multiplication (this should implement the overflow behavior)
3. divide
4. restore the correct sign

Of course, if you exceed the minimum number you start back at -1.
By the way, I felt free to use the `-` operator as its behavior can be implemented with the operators you allowed, but I find it easier to read.

Comment: This works, and that's why I hate it. It uses !! and - which I can't use. Well, atleast I had hope for some time there :)

Comment: You said you can use `!`, and `-x` is equal to `~x+1`, right?

Comment: Right you are. It works with that. I'm going to try and optimize it by having fewer ops, if you can spare the time it would be great if you could help me on that.

Comment: Well,it seems to me that the only operations you can spare are `(~!!(isneg)+1)` and `(~!(isneg)+1)` if you store them in variables. Why you need to _optimize_ this?

Comment: It's the classic BeatTheProf. I've done all I can do on my own and am now reaching out for some help. I have to try and get under 12 ops. The least I've seen so far are 6. I have no idea how.

Comment: Sorry, forgot. I was too busy typing away. Thank you.

Comment: This code relies on undefined behavior, you should change it to use unsigned integer types.

Comment: @Lundin Why do you say so? I thought that the edit in the answer made it clear that rounding towards zero should be implemented. Am I missing some subtle point?

Comment: Oops, sorry, your code relies on implementation-defined behavior, rather (assuming that the code meant to make it positive works). Right-shifting negative values leads to impl.defined behavior, while left-shifting them leads to undefined behavior. Still, there is no reason to use signed integers in bitwise arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this snippet should cover the overflow requirement.

*Please note* that code like this has no purpose in the real world.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t mult_five_eights (uint32_t num)
{
  num = (num << 2) + num; // multiply by 5
  return num >> 3;        // divide by 8
}
```

**EDIT**

Demo program with overflow illustrated. It starts below the largest possible int, then continues past the overflow. Please note that integer overflows are only well-defined for *unsigned* integers.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t mult_five_eights (uint32_t num)
{
  num = (num << 2) + num; // multiply by 5
  return num >> 3;        // divide by 8
}


int main()
{
  uint32_t i;

  for(i=UINT_MAX/5-10; i<UINT_MAX/5+10; i++)
  {
    uint32_t x = i*5/8;
    uint32_t y = mult_five_eights(i);

    printf("%u %u %u ", i, x, y);

    if(x != y)
    {
      printf("error this should never happen");
    }
    printf("\n");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error I get: "Gives -167772161[0xf5ffffff]. Should be -167772160[0xf6000000]"

Comment: @Zanii Then your question is asking for something different than what you expect. The above example clearly shows that the function does exactly the same as x*5/8. If you want to round the number, that's a different matter entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
int five_eights(int val)
{
int ret, car;

car = ((val&7)+((val&1) <<2)) & 5;
car = (car | (car >>2)) &1;

ret = ((val+1) >>1) + ((val+4) >>3) ;

return ret-car;
}
```

Obviously, the above can be further compacted/reduced; the extra variables are for clarity.

Do note that left-shifting is avoided, and overflow is thus impossible.

Comment: This code relies on undefined behavior, you should change it to use unsigned integer types.

Comment: @Lundin I know that unsigned types are easier, but the OQ was about signed ints. IIUC, it are only the (val+1) and (val+4) that could possibly overflow. I could remove them, but that would need a different calculation for the carry / borrow. Maybe later...